# Using += and -= operators in the getter/setters of a Dictionary object

Tags: c#, getter-setter, dictionary

So, I have:

```
Dictionary<some_enumerator, int> available_spaces;
Dictionary<some_enumerator, int> occupied_spaces;
Dictionary<some_enumerator, int> total_spaces;
```

The idea being that as I occupy spaces of given types, I can mark how many spaces of type X are occupied and check to make sure there are spaces available before I call Occupy(enum.space_type) on them.

Currently, I have simple getter/setters for Occupied and Available spaces:

```
public Dictionary<some_enumerator, int> Occupied_Spaces { get; set; }
public Dictionary<some_enumerator, int> Available_Spaces { get; set; }
public Dictionary<some_enumerator, int> Total_Spaces { get; set; }
```

Ideally, I'd like to recalculate the available spaces for each key (by simply subtracting occupied slots from total slots) whenever we call Occupied_Spaces, e.g. instead of doing this:

```
object.Occupied_Spaces[space_type]++;
object.RecalculateSpaces();
```

every time I modify Occupied_Spaces, I'd like to instead do something like (I know this doesn't work, but you get the idea:

```
public Dictionary<some_enumerator> Occupied_Spaces {
     get { return _occupied_spaces; }
     set { _occupied_spaces = value; RecalculateSpaces(); }
}
```

Currently, calling Occupied_Spaces[key]++ does not call the setter in Occupied_Spaces (I tested by throwing a debug print into RecalculateSpaces, which didn't fire).

But I don't know how to override the + (or any other basic operator for that matter) for Dictionaries. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to override these operators? If you are using `int` these are defined already and cannot be overridden.

Comment: `I know this doesn't work` - what about it doesn't work? Loos OK to me.

Comment: Currently, calling Occupied_Spaces[key]++ does not call the setter in Occupied_Spaces (I tested by throwing a debug print into RecalculateSpaces, which didn't fire).

Comment: That's because you are not setting it - you would need to assign a new dictionary to the property for that to happen.

Comment: Just create a function that does the thing you want, and call that function whenever you want it done. `IncrementOccupiedSpace(some_enumerator)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> public Dictionary<some_enumerator> Occupied_Spaces {
>     get { return _occupied_spaces; }
>     set { _occupied_spaces = value; RecalculateSpaces(); }
> }
> ```
>
> Currently, calling Occupied_Spaces[key]++ does not call the setter in Occupied_Spaces (I tested by throwing a debug print into RecalculateSpaces, which didn't fire).

Right. That's because you're not setting `Occupied_Spaces`. Your `Occupied_Spaces` still refers to the exact same dictionary object, only its *contents* have changed.

`Dictionary<,>` does not have any `Change` event for you to subscribe to, so the problem you are facing is unsolvable. What you can do instead is create a custom class that implements `IDictionary<,>`, and use that interface. Your custom class can fire events when the contents of the dictionary change.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the need for synchronization by replacing `Available_Spaces` with this function:

```
GetAvailableSpace(some_enumerator e)
{
    return Total_Spaces[e] - Occupied_Spaces[e];
}
```